# Centering Images Within My HTML Code

Tags: html

I am attempting to center images located in my HTML code as they are currently all showing to the left side. This is within the program Infusionsoft, so not sure if it's just the system that won't let me center with everything I have tried, or if I'm just doing it incorrectly. Any push in the right direction would be helpful.

```
<div style="width:1000px; height:1000px; border:0px; padding:0px;">
<a href="ImageLocation1">
<img alt="single.png"   src="ImageSource1" style="width:280px; height:614px; border:0px solid blue;  float:left;" />
</a>
<a ImageLocation2">
<img alt="Corporate.png"src="ImageSource3" style="width:280px; height:614px; border:0px solid blue; float:left;" />
</a>
<a ImageLocation3">
<img alt="partner.png" src="ImageSource2" style="width:280px; height:614px; border:0px solid blue; float:left;" />
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove the `float` from each image. The float makes the images ignore and center styling you have (which is none). Also, for the "push in the right direction": a) Learn HTML without a GUI; b) Keep styles external and not inline

Comment: Also, your `a` tags are incorrect. Not sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: How are you trying to center them? One on each line and centered to the page? All 3 centered together horizontally on the page?

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful tips, Wes. Definitely agree with learning HTML outside of GUI. Just had to modify an email for a client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different ways of centering your images, individually, or as a group.

Individual:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; border:2px solid red; padding:0px;">
<a href="ImageLocation1">
<img alt="single.png" src="ImageSource1" style="width:48px; height:61px; border:0px solid blue; display:block; margin:0 auto;" />
</a>
<a href="ImageLocation2">
<img alt="Corporate.png" src="ImageSource3"  style="width:48px; height:61px; border:0px solid blue; display:block; margin:0 auto;">
</a>
<a href="ImageLocation3">
<img alt="partner.png" src="ImageSource2" style="width:48px; height:61px; border:0px solid blue; display:block; margin:0 auto;"/>
</a>
</div>
```

Added `display: block` and `margin: 0 auto` to each image

---

Group:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; border:2px solid red; padding:0px;text-align:center">
<a href="ImageLocation1">
<img alt="single.png"   src="ImageSource1" style="width:48px; height:61px; border:0px solid blue;" />
</a>
<a href="ImageLocation2">
<img alt="Corporate.png" src="ImageSource3"  style="width:48px; height:61px; border:0px solid blue;">
</a>
<a href="ImageLocation3">
<img alt="partner.png" src="ImageSource2" style="width:48px; height:61px; border:0px solid blue;" />
</a>
</div>
```

Added `text-align: center` to the wrapper

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4mnLLxz7/

**I changed your height and widths to better present the fiddle, you only need to edit those back to what they were originally.**

If you do not wish to use `display: block` then you can look into `flex` which is a great tool.

[CSS | Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thank you for the guidance on this! The Fiddle website will also come in very handy.

Comment: No problem, happy coding.